# What is the origin of the phrase "And scene!"

Tags: idioms, theater, phrase-origin, cinema

I've run across this phrase a couple of times recently, and was curious about its origins. I would specifically like to know:

1. In what context did the phrase originally arise?
2. Exactly what did it originally mean?

Today, it seems to be used in various contexts; sometimes it [literally means "and the scene ends there"](https://books.google.com/books?id=XYjhAwAAQBAJ&lpg=PT46&ots=VeFN_9RLmY&dq=%22aaaand%20scene%22%20phrase&pg=PT46#v=onepage&q=%22aaaand%20scene%22%20phrase&f=false) (for example in [television synopses](http://www.ew.com/recap/roadies-series-premiere/2)). It can be used slightly more figuratively to mark the [end of a hypothetical situation](https://www.reddit.com/r/TumblrInAction/comments/27l9i9/tw_facebook_uchicago_live_at_the_university_of/ci2jle3). It is also used [to punctuate a story or joke](http://www.escapistmagazine.com/forums/read/18.200801-Do-you-Have-a-catch-phrase-you-use#6624091), to signal both ["I am done speaking](https://whisper.sh/whisper/05193b3a09eb2246690e2fc05e7a5e4087cd2/I-love-using-Aaaand-scene-For-when-I-want-to-stop-taking-to-someone)/[acting](https://answersforactors.net/2010/07/25/things-that-should-never-be-said-in-an-audition/)" and "[you should stop speaking](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2014/01/the-farewell-fave-is-the-best-kind-of-fave/283136/)/[acting](https://bestofama.com/amas/3x7i5z) now," and with other [idiosyncratic implications](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=and...%20scene).

It can be written plainly: *And scene*; or with ellipsis: *And...scene*; or with a bunch of extra a's: *Aaaand scene* (this one is easiest to search for on the web, four a's being the most popular spelling). All of these may take an exclamation mark or period/full stop. Both the *And...* and *Aaaand* versions appear to be approximating an extended drawing-out of the first vowel when the phrase is spoken. I think in all cases the emphasis in the spoken phrase would be on the first word.

I had a vague impression of a couple of different potential origins, and have found some support for both, but nothing definitive. Below are a couple of possible theories, and some of what I've found in support of each.

### Theory 1: **Theatre**

A director or acting teacher would use the line to cut off a scene that has either reached a natural conclusion or that is rambling unproductively.

There's a fair amount of discussion about the use of this phrase in auditions and such (often combined with confusion over whether it's "*and* scene" or "*end* scene"); lots of opinions about where it comes from, but nothing definitive. The only real consensus seems to be that it's annoying/amateurish for actors to use it to end their own scenes, but it happens. See [here](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=674271), [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/comments/jz4xp/is_the_correct_idiomatic_usage_and_scene_or_end/), [here](https://answersforactors.net/2010/07/25/things-that-should-never-be-said-in-an-audition/) etc.

### Theory 2: **Cinema**

A screenwriter, pitching a script, starts with "We open on..." and finishes with "And scene." Could also be a director describing a film.

A recent [short film about three scriptwriters](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1956426/) trying to come up with a pitch was titled *And Scene!* There is also an online ["book club, but for films"](http://andscene.net/) titled And Scene.
Examples of the "We open on . . . And scene!" template definitely exist, as in this [description of a commercial](http://www.adweek.com/agencyspy/jeep-wants-you-to-throw-your-cut-out-the-window/6153) and this [episode synopsis](http://zap2it.com/2008/05/finalewatch-csi-exit-warrick/).
Also, I'm not sure I can quantify it, but the *un-ironic* uses of the phrase seem to be more often of the "describing a cinematic-type scene" variety than the "ending a live-action performance" variety. Similarly, the Hollywood users don't seem to Andy about whether it should really be *end scene*.

---

It could be that the phrase is used in both contexts, but I'm specifically wondering about how it got started. Of course theatre is older than cinema, so one might expect that the term originated in the older medium and was adopted into the newer, but I'm not convinced that's the case.

Note that I'm not suggesting these two theories are the only possibilities; perhaps it is something similar, like film directors originally said it to mean "cut" or acting teachers used it to set up a scene rather than to end one, or it could be something else entirely.

Comment: I'm more familiar with "Aaaaand action!" or "Aaaaand cut!" or "Aaaaand that's a wrap!"

Comment: *Aaaaand lunchtime!*

Comment: I think that's totally dependent on the number of a's involved

Comment: Yes, and you've missed out one of the "a's" and the best one at that!

Comment: I'm confused about the objection to this question. It's a phrase in fairly common English usage, without a clear origin; I'd like to know if anyone has a more definitive answer than I've been able to find. Why the downvote? I realize the phrase itself is sometimes annoying—that's part of why I'd like to know its original usage.

Comment: I think it's a perfectly good question, but it would be difficult to research because the phrase "and scene" is so common that any attempt to use a Google Books (or similar) search to isolate its use in the sense you have in mind will involve wading through a vast field of false positive matches.

Comment: Thanks, @SvenYargs. I agree, it is hard—that's why I couldn't find an answer in my moderately extensive research, and why I noted that *aaaand scene* is the best search phrase. I was hoping that someone with greater knowledge of the entertainment industry on either coast might have an answer, or maybe someone with access to a pertinent source (e.g. back issues of *Variety*). I'm happy to have the question sit here quietly until someone comes along with an answer. It just seems somewhat odd that "too hard" is a reason for (now) two downvotes. Since Rathony's bounty is getting the question ...

Comment: ... more attention, perhaps I'll edit it to make the research more explicit (it has recently come to my attention that the extensive links might not show up as such to everyone, and it's probably better to protect against link rot, anyway) and pull my two hypotheses out into community wiki answers. Maybe that will provide enough of a jumping off point to help someone else find an answer.

Comment: The phrase is not idiomatic.  In fact, I don't recall ever hearing it prior to this question (though I suppose I may have heard it in some old movie about Hollywood and ignored it as jargon).  If you're hearing it a lot I suspect that that's within some particular subculture.

Comment: You  couldn't find an answer in research because it’s almost axiomatic; in daily usage all over stage and screen with an obvious origin.
It arose in theatrical rehearsal; the speech and action of a given scene ended and the cast and crew were stood down.
It originally meant just what it means now: “the scene ends here”…

Comment: … “and… Scene!” isn’t meant to be written; it’s a practical spoken alternative to the Director literally waving a script about while pointing at the written direction: “Scene!”
“and…” with ellipsis arose to preface the command with a warning vocal filler, usually followed by a pause. The drawn-out spelling emphasises preface and pause, sometimes grows into the pretentious sensationalisation of “and… the winner iiiix………… Ludovic!”

Answer (score 2):

I found a helpful source: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=674271

It seems that in rehearsals and improv, to signal that a scene is over, there was a word that a director would use: "Scene."  But adding "And" in the beginning made it flow better and seem more emphatic.

Comment: +1 Thank you for looking into this! That source is actually the second one cited in the question, under "Theory 1". Clearly, my idea to streamline the question by downplaying the citations was a mistake :(.

Comment: @1006a - I think I wasn't reading carefully enough.  Anyway, the googling I did turned out to be interesting.  I tried limiting the time range.  I didn't see any hits (not that I looked at all the n thousands, but still) for this phrase until fairly recently.

Answer (score 1):

### Definition 1:

  An attempt to retract a social faux pas, often a rant, implying, usually jokingly, that the whole thing was just an act.

### Definition 2:

  Derives from auditioning on the stage, when an actor would add it at the end of a scene and mean it literally.
  Person 1: "I hate those Sunday drivers" 
  Person 2: "Me too! This one guy was going like 30 MILES AN HOUR TOO SLOW and I was leaning on my horn but he was eating a donut and was all like WHY DON'T YOU WAKE UP AND GET OUTTA MY WAY!" 
  *Crickets and wide-eyed stares* 
  Person 2: "And... scene."

### Sources:

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=and...%20scene

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This doesn't strike me as a particularly authoritative source for Definition 2.

Comment: That was all I could find online; I didn't do any extensive research into it. Maybe sites like https://www.millionshort.com will find more authoritative sources :)